# List comprehension instead of nested for loop and ifs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a list comprehension equivalent to the nested for loop and conditions

I tried writing

```
lst.append(i,j for i in range(2,num) for j in range(2,i) if num%i==0 if i%j!=0)
```

Which gives me the error:

> Generator expression must be parenthesized

I also tried

```
lst=[(i,j) for i in range(2,num) for j in range(2,i) if num%i==0 if i%j!=0]
```

which doesnt throw error but I am not getting the desired result

```
num=int(input("Enter a number:"))
lst=[]
for i in range(2,num):
    if num%i!=0:
        continue
    else:
        isprime=False
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i%j==0:
                isprime=True
                break
        if not isprime:
            lst.append(i)
for ele in lst:
    print(ele)
```

This program will give the prime factors of a number entered

Comment: Just need to add parenthesis as the error mentions. `lst.append((i,j for i in range(2,num) for j in range(2,i) if num%i==0 and i%j!=0))` and change `if .. if ..` to `if .. and ..`

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post images of code or links to images. Copy and paste as text. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @SunnyPatel is there a shortcut for that link?

Comment: @DSC which link?

Comment: `Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question`. Was wondering if there was a shortcut like `[mcve]`

Comment: this is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: problem with list comprehension is that it doesn't replicate the behaviour of `break`

Comment: This is a very unefficient way to decompose a number in primes. And list comprehension isn't the solution to _all_ problems.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thanks.. this is why I didn't post as an answer.

Comment: I'm sure codereview site has a lot of examples. But with listcomp? no.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to replicate exactly what you have there, you can try something like this:

```
lst = [i for i in range(2, num) if num % i == 0 and all(i % j for j in range(2, i))]
```

Though it's not quite as efficient since it lacks the ability to do break.

If you're instead looking to find all of the primes via list comprehension, this isn't a bad way to accomplish that:

```
lst = [x for x in range(2, num) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple (but not very efficient) way to do it in a list comprehension would be like this:

```
primefactors = [n for n in range(2,num) if num%n==0 and all(n%f for f in range(2,n))]
```